# Extracting Simple Attribute from XML Fields in SQL Server 2008 Table

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008

The goal here is to extract an attribute value from a SQL Server 2008 table column. The column is an XML data type, of course, named 'ProductName'. Here's the sample data

```
<locale en-US="My Text" />
```

And here's my latest attempt at getting to 'My Text'

```
SELECT ProductName.value('/@locale en-US', 'nvarchar(max)')   
AS ProductName FROM MyTable
```

Thanks and good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ProductName.value('(/locale/@en-US)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS ProductName 
FROM MyTable
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    ProductName.value('(/locale/@en-US)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
FROM 
    dbo.MyTable
```

The `/locale` part of the XPath expression matches the `<locale>` element, while the `@en-US` part matches the `en-US` **attribute** of that XML element.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @xml xml =
'<root>
  <locale en-US="My Text" />
</root>'

select @xml.value('(/root/locale/@en-US)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
```

**Result**

My Text